# as400 I series JDBC Connect

Tags: python, db2, ibm-midrange

I have been trying to connect as400 (IBM DB2 i series) server using JDBC however the code I have written is neither giving any exception nor printing anything. Can any one please help with if I am doing anything wrong or required to change any server side configuration.

```
import jaydebeapi
import os
import configparser

class IbmDb2(object):

        def __init__(self):
            
            print("Initializing...")
            self.thisfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, "..")))
            self.configfile = os.path.join(self.thisfolder, 'config', 'config.ini')
            self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            self.config_read = self.config.read(self.configfile)
            
            self.driver = self.config.get('DRIVER', 'driver')
            self.user = self.config.get('USER', 'user')
            self.password = self.config.get('PASSWORD', 'password')
            
            # Load the Netsuite JDBC driver
            self.jar_path = os.path.join(self.thisfolder, 'jars', "jt400.jar")
            print(f"JAR Path: {self.jar_path}")
            self.conn_str = "jdbc:as400://XX.XX.XX.XX:9099/WM410BASD"
            
            self.connection = jaydebeapi.connect(self.driver, self.conn_str, [self.user, self.password] , 'C:/google_analytics_data/db2-to-bq/jars/jt400.jar', )
            print(self.connection)
            print("Connection success")

            # Establish the connection
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute('select count(*) from WM410BASD.PHPICK00')
            results = self.cursor.fetchall()
            print(results)
            self.connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db2data = IbmDb2()
```

Comment: Maybe the password prompt popup is displayed but you don't see it, try adding ';prompt=false' to you connection string

Comment: I have made connection string like this: self.conn_str = "jdbc:as400://xx.xx.xx.xx:9099/WM410BASD;prompt=false;" however it is still not working. the code only printing till this line print(f"JAR Path: {self.jar_path}")

Answer (score 0):

Check your iseries for CPF9898 Messages. They indicate Authorization Errors.
You should find them in QSECOFR or the users log.
You could also check the users last login or invalid password checks.